# Calculate the estimate percentage of impressions at top

Tags: estimation

Ok, So I'm trying to get percentage estimate of how many impressions are at the top of a search page between the hour. Based on the metrics: $Impressions,\,Previous\,Impressions,\,Top\,Impression\,\%\,\&\,Previous\,Top\,Impressions\,\%$.

For ease we can put these as the following variables:

$x = Total\,Impressions\,(for\,the\,day\,so\,far)$
$y = Previous\,Impressions\,(Total\,Impressions\,for\,the\,day\,an\,hour\,ago)$
$a = Top\,Impression\,\%\,(for\,the\,day\,so\,far)$
$b = Previous\,Top\,Impression\,\%\,(Total\,from\,an\,hour\,ago)$

From this, I want to estimate what percentage of the impressions over the past hour were at the top position. To do this I'm using the following:

$( x(a) - b(y) ) / ( x - y ) = EST.$

So to put this into action if the following is true:

$x = 250$
$y = 213$
$a = 67\%$
$b = 66\%$

Based on the above math that would mean the estimation percentage would be $72\%$.

So the maths reckons from the $37$ new impressions $72\%$ of them were possibly at the top of the page. This seems reasonable but in some cases, it totally breaks down. E.g. if there is less than ten of a difference the estimation becomes wild. Which is to be expected. But I also get issues like in the following case:

$x = 250$
$y = 240$
$a = 70\%$
$b = 66\%$

The estimation would be $166\%$. Which for our estimation purpose cant be true. I could always condition this not to be allowed to go above $100\%$, But I feel there is probably a better way to go about this.

What I wanted to know is, if anyone had any thoughts on what would be a more accurate way to try and get the estimate? If not, is there any particular issues with the current math that might cause more upset like it is useless with a difference less than ten?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thank you @JoséCarlosSantos I will look into sorting this as soon as I can thanks.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "impression" ?

Comment: @JeanMarie an impression could be anything really. Let's try it this way: let's say we have 100 people at the beach. out of those 100 people, 66% of them were in the water. Then an hour later there are 120 people at the beach and 67% of them are in the water. So in the past hour what percentage of the new people who came to the beach entered the water. Doesn't matter what impressions are its just a number. Could be anything. But in this case, an impression is when a and object with a  relative term is searched for and displayed to a user.